# django-import-export :ForeignKey with many fields

Tags: python, django, export-to-excel, django-import-export

I need just export data from my admin. My code now looks like:

```
models.py

 from django.db import models
from services.models import Services,PromoCodes,CauseOfReservedPromocodes
# Create your models here.

class User(models.Model):
    name=models.CharField(max_length=200)
    surname=models.CharField(max_length=200)
    email=models.EmailField()
    password=models.CharField(max_length=200)
   telephone=models.PositiveIntegerField(max_length=12,blank=True,null=True)
    userRequest=models.ForeignKey('UsersRequests', blank=True, null=True, on_delete=models.CASCADE)

    def __str__(self):
        return self.name + " " + self.surname


class UsersRequests(models.Model):
    date = models.DateField()
    requestChannel = models.CharField(max_length=30)
    problem = models.CharField(max_length=200)
    solution = models.CharField(max_length=200)

    def __unicode__(self):
        return str(self.date) + " " + str(self.requestChannel) + " " + str(self.problem) + " " + str(self.solution)
```

And my admin.py is:

```
from django.contrib import admin
from .models import User,UsersRequests
from import_export import resources, widgets, fields
from import_export.admin import ImportExportModelAdmin,ExportMixin

class UsersResource(resources.ModelResource):
 class Meta:
        model = User
        fields = ('id', 'name', 'email', 'telephone', 'userRequest')

class UserAdmin(ImportExportModelAdmin):
    resource_class = UsersResource

@admin.register(User)
class UserAdmin(ImportExportModelAdmin):
    search_fields = ('name', 'surname', 'email', 'telephone')
```

I try everything to get userRequest work, but it send just integer - id for userRequest. How to get full data from class UsersRequests(models.Model)?

Comment: I also try this:
`class FullNameForeignKeyWidget(ForeignKeyWidget):
    def get_queryset(self, value, row):
        return self.model.objects.filter(
            date__iexact=row["date"],
            requestChannel__iexact=row["requestChannel"],
            problem__iexact=row["problem"],
            solution__iexact=row["solution"]
        )


class UsersResource(resources.ModelResource):
    userRequest = fields.Field(column_name='userRequest', attribute='userRequest',
                           widget=FullNameForeignKeyWidget(UsersRequests))`
but it's not working too

Answer (score 0):

You should point all related field exactly, like:

```
class UsersResource(resources.ModelResource):
    class Meta:
        model = User
        fields = ('id', 'name', 'email', 'telephone',
        'userRequest__date', 'userRequest__problem')

@admin.register(User)
class UserAdmin(ImportExportModelAdmin):
    resource_class = UsersResource
    search_fields = ('name', 'surname', 'email', 'telephone')
```

And so on

Comment: userRequest
7
The result is the same. I get id for userRequest

Comment: you defined you Import Class two times and register very basic @admin.register(User)
class UserAdmin(ImportExportModelAdmin):
    search_fields = ('name', 'surname', 'email', 'telephone') delete it and register one what above

Comment: what it should look like? i need to send this 
`class UsersAdmin(admin.ModelAdmin):
    search_fields = ('name', 'email', 'telephone')`
for search field in admin pannel

Comment: see above, smth like that

Comment: And what if I want to add 1 more class here? Something like this:
`class UserServices(models.Model):
    service=models.ForeignKey(Services,on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    user=models.ForeignKey(User,on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    end_time = models.DateField('end time')

    def __str__(self):
        return str(self.user)+" "+str(self.service)`

Comment: I didnt understand the question